# How to increase the size of an unicode icon awesome fonts relative to its container with CSS

Tags: html, css, unicode, font-awesome

How to increase the size of an unicode icon awesome fonts relative to its container with CSS?

```
.iconTimes:before {
      display: block;
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      content: "\f00d"; 
 }
```

Comment: isn't **font-size** working?

Comment: You can define container height in `rem` and also use `rem` for `font-size` in that `.iconTimes` element.

Comment: Thanks GiuServ and connexo. font-size solves the problem. If you want to post as an answer I give my vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `em` units for the same. Say your HTML is

```
<div class="container">
  <i class="iconTimes"></i>
</div>
```

Your CSS could be

```
.container { 
   font-size: 14px; //if this was not declared `.iconTimes` would have 2 x 16px = 32px
}

.iconTimes {
    font-size: 2em; //this will be 2 x 14px = 28px
}

.iconTimes:before {
    display: block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f00d";
 }
```

[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/GjaRwz)

> If the font-size is not mentioned for any element it will be **by default '16px'**, which means if you use '2em' and its parent's font-size is NOT declared then it will be 2x16px = 32px.

Comment: Thank you Nikhil for the full explanation. It Works very well.

Comment: @josei .. Small edit made. If the font-size is not mentioned for any element it will be by default `16px` which means if you use `2em` whos parents font-size is not declared then it will be 2x16px = 32px. You can mark the answer as accepted if you wish.

Comment: Thanks again Nikhil.